# How to deploy solr war file in weblogic server

Tags: deployment, solr, weblogic

The solr war file needs to be deployed in the weblogic server. So when the weblogic starts, the solr server must also get started (instead of using the default solr port which is 8983, it should be accessible through the weblogic port).

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work, etc.? Be advised that this configuration is _not_ supported in any official way, so you'll mainly be on your own without much reference material.

Answer (score 1):

From Solr 5.0+ Support for deploying Solr into servers (like tomcat )no longer supported.

Solr should be a standalone server, and it's very easy just, follow these [steps](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I could deploy solr in tomcat. I just want to get solr started when the weblogic starts and in the same port number of weblogic.